# Why do water sounds different at different levels?

Tags: waves, acoustics, everyday-life, wavelength, harmonics

I observed that when we fill a water bottle it sounds different at different levels of height.
means it sounds different while filling at $\frac{1}4$ level and different at $\frac{1}2$.

I just want to ask why it happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! The sound pitch is based upon the height of the air column above the water, in which the standing sound wave is vibrating. As this air column decreases in size, the pitch gets higher. The same way any musical instrument works. E.g. in a pipe organ, the largest pipes create the low notes and the smallest pipes create the high notes.

Answer (score 5):

Because acoustic resonance happens at different frequencies depending on the height of the air column above the water level.